# where do i use no data found exception on FOR statement inside a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, toad

i have the next question:

Im not very good at DBs, i've been requested to add a "No data found exception" to a stored procedure.

This is the SP:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TABLE."SP_UPD"
(
  PERROR OUT VARCHAR2
)
AS
BEGIN

FOR TMP_TABLE IN 
(SELECT FIELDS FROM TABLES)

 --I need to verify HERE if the for returns--
--no values, because once the loop starts it automaticaly updates tables--

LOOP
 BEGIN
  CODE
  MORE CODE
 END
END LOOP;


I added the exception here, at the bottom before the last backslash, is this right?:
    EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
        perror:='error message';
        return;
    END;   
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do **anything**, because - in a cursor `FOR` loop (which is what you have), Oracle will **skip** everything between `LOOP` and `END LOOP` if cursor doesn't return any rows.

So: if `select fields from tables` doesn't return anything , `code` and `more code` won't ever be executed.